# What is the relevance of preservation of trace in completely postive trace preserving (CPTP) maps?

Tags: density-matrix, quantum-operation

Why is the trace preserving part necessary? Is it not enough if it can take all matrices to matrices of trace 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those maps are linear, so if it preserves the trace of trace 1 matrices then it preserves the trace of any other matrix.

We just don't need to restrict ourselves by considering only trace 1 matrices (from mathematical point of view).

Comment: I think the question was, why can't we consider something like $$ \tilde{C}(\rho)=\frac{C(\rho)}{\mathrm{Tr}[C(\rho)]}$$ for a non trace preserving $C$ a quantum channel? (It said "[...] it can take all matrices to matrices of trace 1")

Comment: In this case $\tilde{C}$ is not linear.